# Hotmail and Onedrive API program

Tags: api-design, hotmail, onedrive, windows-live-mail

Please tell me some source website and sample coding format to work on Hotmail and Onedrive API.

I want to work on Hotmail to fetch the mail from the Hotmail account via API concept.

And in case for Onedrive I want to fetch and send file to/from Microsoft Onedrive.

Comment: from onedrive-api tagwiki: [developer site](http://dev.onedrive.com./). This probably is what you're looking for....

Comment: You can use the [Live SDK API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826535.aspx). Also see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659752.aspx).

Comment: Thanks to give me some suggestion.